# how to merge a number of lists in to one list

Tags: python

Hi i have a lists like this

```
['ID 1d6b:0002']
['ID 1d6b:0002']
['ID 1d6b:0001']
['ID 1d6b:0001']
['ID 1d6b:0001']
['ID 1d6b:0001']
['ID 1d6b:0001']
['ID 0b38:0010']
['ID 093a:2510']
```

I want this to one list.Please help me out with this

Comment: many lists floating around in midair.

Comment: @all these lists are not stored in any variable. this is output of executing one of the commands and after slicing it i got that result.

Comment: Maybe some code could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
old_list = [
['ID 1d6b:0002'],
['ID 1d6b:0002'],
['ID 1d6b:0001'],
['ID 1d6b:0001'],
['ID 1d6b:0001'],
['ID 1d6b:0001'],
['ID 1d6b:0001'],
['ID 0b38:0010'],
['ID 093a:2510']]


new_list = [x[0] for x in old_list]
```

This uses list comprehension to create a new list that contains the first elements ([0]) all on the lists in the old list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please provide some details to your answer like what new_list = [x[0] for x in old_list] is doing. I assume the OP can't understand this as per the level of his/her question. :)